# skip next rule if pattern is matched

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rule that looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?marker=$1
```

I need to skip this rule if the url is /admin

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ /maps/admin [S=1]
```

followed by the first rule above but that is giving a **The page isn't redirecting properly** error.

Answer (score 0):

Try another approaching by using [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !^admin/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?marker=$1 [L]
```

Also, don't forget to add the `[L]` (Last) flag to your rules where appropriate. Otherwise it will continue processing them into one large compounded rule.

Comment: That does not seem to be working. I need it so that if the url is /admin it will go to /admin and not try to go to index.php?marker=$1. Or in other words if the user wants to go to the admin it goes there and then does nothing else/ skips the rewrite rule.

Comment: I am not sure what you tried. Comment back with the URLs. Also note the `[L]` flag update.

Comment: I tried 
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ /maps/admin [S=1]
folowed by
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?marker=$1